# how to show message if no data found after Parsing

Tags: java, android

```
public class circularlistparsing extends ActivityGroup {

    public int currentPage = 1;
    public ListView lisView1;
    static final String KEY_ITEM = "docdetails";
    static final String KEY_ITEM2 = "info";
    static final String KEY_NAME1 = "";
    static final String KEY_NAME = "heading";
    static final String KEY_DATE = "date";
    public Button btnNext;
    public Button btnPre;
    public static String url = "http://dev.taxmann.com/TaxmannService/TaxmannService.asmx/GetCircularList";
    TextView txtreord;
    TextView totalpage;
    TextView pagenumber;
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    TextView title;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        txtreord = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.recored);
        totalpage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalpage);
        pagenumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pagenumber);
        title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);

        title.setText("Cirrcular");
        // listView1
        lisView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        // Next
        btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
        // Perform action on click
        btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                currentPage = currentPage + 1;

                // new YourTask().execute();
                ShowData();
                pagenumber.setText("Of" + currentPage + "]");
            }
        });

        // Previous
        btnPre = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPre);
        // Perform action on click
        btnPre.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                currentPage = currentPage - 1;

                // new YourTask().execute();
                ShowData();
                pagenumber.setText("Of" + currentPage + "]");
            }
        });


        ShowData();
    }

    public void ShowData() {
        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(url); // getting XML

        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);

        NodeList n2 = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM2);

        int displayPerPage = 10; // Per Page
        int TotalRows = nl.getLength();

        txtreord.setText(TotalRows + "Records|"); // number of records

        int indexRowStart = ((displayPerPage * currentPage) - displayPerPage);
        int TotalPage = 0;
        if (TotalRows <= displayPerPage) {
            TotalPage = 1;
        } else if ((TotalRows % displayPerPage) == 0) {
            TotalPage = (TotalRows / displayPerPage);
        } else {
            TotalPage = (TotalRows / displayPerPage) + 1; // 7
            TotalPage = (int) TotalPage; // 7
        }

        totalpage.setText("Page[" + TotalPage);

        int indexRowEnd = displayPerPage * currentPage; // 5
        if (indexRowEnd > TotalRows) {
            indexRowEnd = TotalRows;
        }

        // Disabled Button Next
        if (currentPage >= TotalPage) {
            btnNext.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            btnNext.setEnabled(true);
        }

        // Disabled Button Previos
        if (currentPage <= 1) {
            btnPre.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            btnPre.setEnabled(true);
        }

        // Load Data from Index
        int RowID = 1;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        HashMap<String, String> map;

        // RowID
        if (currentPage > 1) {
            RowID = (displayPerPage * (currentPage - 1)) + 1;
        }

        for (int i = indexRowStart; i < indexRowEnd; i++) {
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);

            Element e2 = (Element) n2.item(i);

            String date = e2.getAttribute(KEY_DATE);
            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value

            map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("RowID", String.valueOf(RowID));

            map.put(KEY_DATE, date);



            String mytime = date;
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyymmdd");
            Date myDate = null;
            try {
                myDate = dateFormat.parse(mytime);

            } catch (ParseException t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            } catch (java.text.ParseException t) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                t.printStackTrace();
            }

            SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            String finalDate = timeFormat.format(myDate);

            // System.out.println("rrrrrrrrrrrrr"+finalDate);

            String Heading = parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME);

            int a = Heading.indexOf("|");
            String beforeSubString = Heading.substring(0, a);
            String afterSubString = Heading.substring(a, Heading.length())
                    .replace("|", "") + "[" + finalDate + "]";
            // String
            // final1="<b>"+beforeSubString+"<b>"+"|"+afterSubString.replace("|",
            // "|\n")
            // .replace("|", "");
            // String k=Html.fromHtml(final1).toString();
            //
            // Html.fromHtml(final1);

            map.put(KEY_NAME, beforeSubString);
            map.put(KEY_NAME1, afterSubString);

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            menuItems.add(map);

            RowID = RowID + 1;

        }

        SimpleAdapter sAdap;
        sAdap = new SimpleAdapter(circularlistparsing.this, menuItems,
                R.layout.list_item,
                new String[] { "RowID", KEY_NAME1, KEY_NAME }, new int[] {
                        R.id.ColRowID, R.id.ColName, R.id.textView1 });
        lisView1.setAdapter(sAdap);

        lisView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent i = new Intent(circularlistparsing.this, detail.class);
                // sending data to new activity
                // i.putExtra("product", product);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });

    }
}
```

This is My Source code i want to Display message if there is no data found after Parsing  coz in some case no data found please see my code and please tell me how i will Put code so that it show messge if data is not Found right now if data is not there then application becomes close .

Answer (score 0):

You can return the data or `null` in your method and based on that check if you get `null` on invoking that method. If it is `null` simply display that there is no data

Answer (score 0):

you can check **`intRowStart`**  and **`intRowEnd`** are same or not

if same then not to show data and

show **`dialog with no data`** found

and not to set Adapter..

when use click on ok button then again go back to get Data....

Comment: whether it shows any error..??
if not then use try catch whether any exception occurs or not...

Comment: first store your elements(int TotalRows = nl.getLength())
and next time check check that value with new rows if it bigger then last one then show data else show dialog of "No New data"..
|check this one..

Answer (score 0):

> You can check the ArrayList(menuItems ) is empty or not.

```
if(menuItems.isEmpty())
{
    No record found.
}
else
{

   set the listAdapter.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setEmptyView(android.view.View)

Do not invent bycicles.